# What does a '-' signify in neo4j import's stdout?

Tags: neo4j

I'm bulk-importing data from CSV into neo4j (v3.5.25) and have noticed that the import stdout occasionally contains dashes ('-') rather than dots ('.'): -

```
(4/4) Post processing 2020-12-16 15:33:27.150+0000
  Estimated required memory usage: 1020.01 MB
..-..-.-.. .......... .......... .......... ..........   5% ∆24s 455ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  10% ∆13s 17ms
```

1. Can someone tell me what these `-` symbols signify?
2. Are there other characters that can be omitted?

Comment: Are you using https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/? If so, my gut feeling is that it could mean some entries were skipped. Did you use any of the --skip option (--skip-bad-relationships, --skip-duplicate-nodes)?

Comment: Thanks. We are using `/var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j-admin import` and we do use `--ignore-missing-nodes` but it would be nice to have an official description of these (potentially) cryptic characters somewhere.